# bigcommerce-stencil/citadel repo not found

Tags: bigcommerce, jspm

I'm following the installation and setup instructions for stencil [found here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/javascript-utilities). Everything seems to have worked correctly until I run the `jspm install` command. Here is the output:

```
$ jspm install
     Looking up npm:lodash
     Updating registry cache...
     Looking up github:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-utils
     Looking up github:bigcommerce-stencil/citadel
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-url
     Looking up github:vakata/jstree
     Looking up github:hubspot/pace

warn Using local override for github:hubspot/pace@1.0.2
     Looking up github:jackmoore/zoom
     Looking up github:browserstate/history.js
     Looking up github:asyncly/EventEmitter2
     Looking up github:ftlabs/fastclick
     Looking up github:kenwheeler/slick
     Looking up github:casperin/nod
     Looking up github:components/jquery
     Looking up github:caolan/async
     Looking up github:bigcommerce-labs/foundation

err  Repo github:bigcommerce-stencil/citadel not found!

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

If I run the command again, it looks like the `github:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-utils` repo is not found:

```
$ jspm install
     Looking up npm:lodash
     Updating registry cache...
     Looking up github:bigcommerce-stencil/citadel
     Looking up github:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-utils
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-url
     Looking up github:casperin/nod
     Looking up github:kenwheeler/slick
     Looking up github:asyncly/EventEmitter2
     Looking up github:vakata/jstree
     Looking up github:browserstate/history.js
     Looking up github:hubspot/pace

warn Using local override for github:hubspot/pace@1.0.2
     Looking up github:bigcommerce-labs/foundation
     Looking up github:components/jquery
     Looking up github:jackmoore/zoom
     Looking up github:ftlabs/fastclick
     Looking up github:caolan/async
     Downloading npm:lodash@3.10.1
     Downloading github:hubspot/pace@1.0.2
     Downloading github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0
     Downloading github:casperin/nod@2.0.10
     Downloading github:browserstate/history.js@1.8.0
     Downloading github:bigcommerce-labs/foundation@5.5.3
     Downloading github:vakata/jstree@3.2.1
     Downloading github:asyncly/EventEmitter2@0.4.14
     Downloading github:jackmoore/zoom@1.7.14
     Downloading github:ftlabs/fastclick@1.0.6
     Downloading github:kenwheeler/slick@1.5.5

err  Repo github:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-utils not found!

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

If I run it again, I get the original output. It seems to keep randomly changing. So, the question is, why can't these repos be found?

I know I have access to the repos because if I try to clone it directly, it works fine with the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/bigcommerce-stencil/citadel.git
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you followed these steps? https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-stencil-cli-1#Register_jspm

Comment: Yes, I followed these steps exactly. Oddly, I just made a change to my Github access token, and it seemed to solve the problem. Before I had the three boxes checked for scopes `repo:status`, `repo_deployment`, and `public_repo`, as the docs instruct. However, I just edited the token and checked the parent "repo" box, rather than the three individual ones below it, and now the `jspm install` command is working.

Comment: @Alyss, that is definitely the issue. If I change it back, I get the error again. I think you should update the documentation to clearly state that you need to check the "repo" checkbox. Checking the individual permissions mentioned in the docs does not seem to work.

Comment: Let our documentation team know so we can revise that. Thanks for the unintentional discovery :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for getting back to me! Did you let the documentation team know, or were you asking me to do so?

Comment: If you take a look, the instructions have been updated: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-stencil-cli-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that was causing this was the Github Access Token required `repo` to be checked and not just the subresources associated with `repo`. Stencil documentation has been updated to reflect this.